# APEX test class - "Constructors Can not be static"

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

I have a Trigger that creates a record in a custom object ("Services__c") when an Opportunity is marked as "Closed Won". Once closed won, a new Service record will be inserted, and:

- Service Record Type will be set based on information provided in the Opportunity
- Opportunity Team Members will be pulled into the Service record
- Some fields in the Service record will be pre-populated

The trigger works perfectly, but I am having trouble writing an APEX class/test method to promote it to Production! Can anyone help point out my issue? I am getting the error: *"Constructors Can not be static"*

**HERE IS THE TRIGGER**

```
trigger ServiceCreation on Opportunity (after update) {

 map<id,Opportunity> oldValueMap = Trigger.oldMap;

FOR(OPPORTUNITY OPP:TRIGGER.NEW){

    Opportunity oldOpp = oldValueMap.get(OPP.id);
    //Check if Opportunity is Won, is a Centinel Integration, and is not marked as a Plan Upgrade
    if (OPP.isWon && !oldOpp.isWon && Opp.Platform__c <>'Cardinal 2ID' && Opp.Type<>'Plan Upgrade'){

         Services__c SVC = new Services__c();
        //Queries Opportunity Team Member Table, returns list of User IDs and Team Member Roles
        for(OpportunityTeamMember teamMember:[select UserID,TeamMemberRole from OpportunityTeamMember where OpportunityId=:OPP.ID]){
           //Sets Service Owner and Client Manager in Service record based on Opportunity Team Members
            if (teamMember.TeamMemberRole=='Activation Manager'){
                SVC.OwnerId = teammember.userId;
            } else if (teamMember.TeamMemberRole=='Client Manager'){
                SVC.Client_Manager__c = teammember.userId;
            }  

        }
        //Queries Service Record Types and Developer Names 
        Map<string,id> serviceRTMap = new Map<string,id>();
            for (RecordType RT:[select id,developerName from RecordType where SobjectType='Services__c']){
                   serviceRTMap.put(rt.developerName,rt.id);
            }
        //Set record type of Service based on Opportunity Information
        if (opp.Product__c=='Consumer Authentication'){
            Svc.RecordTypeId = serviceRTMap.get('Authentication');
        } else if (opp.Product__c == 'Payment Brands' && opp.Payment_Brands__c.contains('PayPal')){
            Svc.RecordTypeId = serviceRTMap.get('PayPal');
        } else {
            Svc.RecordTypeId = serviceRTMap.get('Payment_Brand');
        }
        //Prefill subset of Service fields, upon creation, with data from the Opportunity
        Svc.Name = Opp.Name; 
        Svc.Register_Date__c = Opp.CloseDate;
        Svc.Stage__c = '1-Boarding';
        Svc.Status__c = 'Registered';
        Svc.Related_Opportunity__c = Opp.ID;
        svc.account__c = Opp.AccountID;
        svc.Sales_Rep__c = Opp.OwnerID;
        svc.Platform__c = Opp.Platform__c;
        svc.Product__c = Opp.Product__c;
        svc.Payment_Brand__c = Opp.Payment_Brands__c;
        svc.Partner__c = Opp.Partner__c;
        svc.Monthly_Transactions__c = Opp.Monthly_Transactions__c;
        svc.Monthly_Revenue__c = Opp.Monthly_Revenue__c;
        svc.Set_Up_Fee__c = Opp.Set_up_Fee__c;
        svc.Annualized_Revenue__c = Opp.Amount;
        svc.RBA__c = opp.Rules__c;
        svc.Adapter__c = Opp.Adapter__c;
        svc.Projected_Activation_Date__c = Opp.Projected_Activation_Date__c;
        Insert SVC;
    }
}
}
```

**HERE IS THE CLASS**

```
Public class TestServiceCreation {
Static testMethod void verifyOpportunityInsert() {
    //data preparation
    Opportunity Opp = new Opportunity(
        Name = 'Consumer Authentication Test',
        StageName = 'Closed Won',
        CloseDate = system.today(),
        Type = 'New Business',
        Platform__c = 'Cardinal Centinel',
        Product__c = 'Consumer Authentication',
        Payment_Brands__c = 'Verified by Visa',
        Rules__c = 'Yes',
        Monthly_Transactions__c = 150,
        Monthly_Revenue__c = 250,
        Set_up_Fee__c = 1500);
   //Insert Opportunity
    test.startTest();
    insert Opp;
    Test.stopTest();

    //Verify the Opportunity was inserted, and update the Stage to Closed Won
 Static testMethod void verifyOppInsertAndUpdate 
    List<Opportunity> insertedOpportunities = [SELECT Name, StageName, Type, Platform__c, Product__c, Payment_Brands__c, Rules__c, Monthly_Transactions__c, Monthly_Revenue__c, Set_Up_Fee__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Name = 'Consumer Authentication Test'];
   Opp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    Test.startTest();
    Update Opp;
    Test.StopTest();

    //Verify the Service was inserted, and fields were brought over
Static testMethod void verifyServiceCreation    
    List<Services__c> insertedServices__c;
    Services__c SVC = [SELECT Name, Account__c, Related_Opportunity__c,Status__c, Stage__c, Platform__c, Product__c, Payment_Brand__c, Register_Date__c, RBA__c, Monthly_Transactions__c, Monthly_Revenue__c, Set_Up_Fee__c FROM Services__c];
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Name, 'Consumer Authentication');
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Account__c, Opp.AccountId);
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Related_Opportunity__c, Opp.ID);
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Register_Date__c, Opp.CloseDate);
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Status__c, 'Registered');
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Stage__c, '1-Boarding');
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Platform__c, 'Cardinal Centinel');
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Product__c, 'Consumer Authentication');
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Payment_Brand__c, 'Verified by Visa');
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Monthly_Transactions__c, 1500);
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Monthly_Revenue__c, 250);
    System.assertEquals(SVC.Set_Up_Fee__c, 1500);
    System.assertEquals(SVC.RBA__c, 'Yes');
}
```

}

Comment: You don't have a return type on your method test() thus the compiler thinks it a constructor instead (and is why its complaining about the static keyword).

Answer (score 3):

See the example below for how the [test method](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) should look. You can use either format for test methods.

```
@isTest
private class TestServiceCreation {

    @isTest
    static void test1() {
        // Test Logic
    }

    static testMethod void test2() {
        // More test logic
    }

}
```

There are some other issues with your trigger and class:

The `insert record;` and `update record;` lines in your test class will cause a compilation error. It should be `insert opp;` instead.

Your trigger has several SOQL queries and an Insert inside of for loops which means you code will not handle large batches of records. You need to [bulkify](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3a_Bulkify_Your_Code) your trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting "Public" before "static" on the test method.

Also, I would recommend encapsulating the logic in separate methods more like you will see described in this blog: http://jessealtman.com/2013/09/proper-unit-test-structure-in-apex/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks...I used the article and updated the class in the above post...I am now getting an error saying "Only top-level class variables can be static". I am also getting Errors when testing: "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject". Can you look at the new class @snugsfbay @BarCotter? ANY more help would be appreciated...sorry if this is basic, but I am not a developer and had to teach myself how to write this, and it needs deployed to production this week!

Comment: Thats very cool that you have taught yourself to write this.  However, I would be concerned about not having the right level of support if/when this breaks in production at a critical time.

Comment: We are in process of getting developer support, though will not have in next 2 days (unfortunately...been waiting for approval on that for awhile, which is why I had to take this into my own hands)

Comment: @KCrock88 I suggest that you create a new Question to answer the "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" error. As for the test not compiling, you are missing the opening and closing brackets in the test method name `static testMethod void verifyServiceCreation` should be `static testMethod void verifyServiceCreation() {`